How to implement "Experience Replay" in a DCGAN with CIFAR-10
I need to implement the "Experience Replay" technique in the following class for a DCGAN working with the CIFAR-10 dataset. The code should go between the training of the Discriminator and the Generator (right where the comment appears) but I don't know how to approach it. Please, I would appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this. Thank you.
class GAN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.experience_replay = []

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.d_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="d_loss")
        self.g_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="g_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.d_loss_metric, self.g_loss_metric]

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images[0])[0]
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        generated_images = self.generator([real_images[1],random_latent_vectors])

        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images[0]], axis=0)

        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        combined_labels = tf.concat([real_images[1], real_images[1]], axis=0)

        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator([combined_images, combined_labels])
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )
        
        **# EXPERIENCE REPLAY CODE MUST BE HERE...**

        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator([self.generator([real_images[1],random_latent_vectors]), real_images[1]])
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))


        self.d_loss_metric.update_state(d_loss)
        self.g_loss_metric.update_state(g_loss)
        return {
            "d_loss": self.d_loss_metric.result(),
            "g_loss": self.g_loss_metric.result(),
        }

I tried this code but it doesn't work:
        self.experience_replay.extend(real_images.numpy()) # This atribute must be created in the class.

        if len(self.experience_replay) >= batch_size:
            print ("Doing Experience Replay...")
            replay_indices = np.random.choice(len(self.experience_replay), batch_size, replace=False)
            replay_samples = np.array(self.experience_replay)[replay_indices]
            
            combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, replay_samples], axis=0)
            labels = tf.concat([tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0)

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
                d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
            grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
            self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
            )


